# Owl carousel items order starts with the item in the middle of the list

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I've searched through this site and on other sites, but I couldn't find an option for how to set the default active slide when the carousel is loaded to be the first in the list, according to the order in which the HTML tags were written.

It seems that, by default, Owl carousel takes a list of items, say Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4 and Item5, determines where is the middle of the list (Item3) and loads that item as the current first slide.

This can create some confusions when you're trying to work with callbacks and URLhashListeners. Then you would have to re-number your list starting from the item in the middle, which is not the optimal way to work with that.

Maybe I missed something, does Owl carousel have an option for which item is loaded first in the slide order? I'm using version 2.0.

Comment: OK, so now I understood something interesting. It seems that the first item loaded in the carousel by default is not also the first item in the URL hash list. So you can use startPosition: 0 to make the carousel load the first item in the list as the first slide, but when you click the first link in the list of items which use the data-hash attribute, the carousel will load the item in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much struggle and hair-pulling I found out it was all caused by this option:

```
loop: true
```

I disabled looping and now all the slides play in the logical order. I really hope this guy who made this otherwise awesome carousel would document it better.